# Access key and value of an array with nested item and key in smarty template?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty

I'm assigning an `array` named `$additional_infos` from php file to a smarty template file.

```
foreach ($results as $row) {

    $additional_infos[] = array('informations_client' => $row['informations_client'], 'field_type' => $row['field_type']);

}
```

The array print is like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [informations_client] => Nom
            [field_type] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [informations_client] => Prénom
            [field_type] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [informations_client] => Adresse
            [field_type] => 2
        )
)
```

I can display this in template like this :

```
{foreach name=outer item=contact from=$additional_infos}
    <hr />
    {foreach key=key item=item from=$contact}
         {$key}: {$item}<br />
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

It works fine :

```
informations_client: Nom

field_type: 1

informations_client: Prénom

field_type: 1
```

I would like to access directly to `informations_client` or `field_typ`e but i have smarty errors.

I would like to use something like this `{$item. field_type}`

How can i do that ?

Comment: You can use {$item['field_type']}

Comment: @PavelPetrov I’ve spend an hour on this and finally decided to find some help on SO. Just after i ask my question, i discover i could access directly like this in a single foreach : `{$contact.informations_client}`

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to delete my question since i found a solution immediately after asking the question (i was stuck since an hour).

I prefer post my answer if it can help. Maybe it could be improved :

```
{foreach name=outer item=contact from=$additional_infos}

     {$contact.informations_client} -  {$contact.field_type}

{/foreach}
```